# Аутентификация Laravel + Vue.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Хочу на новом проекте **Laravel** + **Vue** использовать аутентификацию и регистрацию, в какую сторону смотреть? Использовать **JWT** токены или есть готовое решение для **Vue**?

Answer (score 1):

- **frontend + backend**. Есть готовое решение у фреймворка **Laravel** - [Jetstream](https://jetstream.laravel.com/1.x/introduction.html).
- **backend** Пакеты(например): [Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport), [Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum).

Лично я использую **Passport** + самописный **frontend**.

Видео материалы:

[Andre Madarang](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5S23KS_-bU&list=PLEhEHUEU3x5q-xB1On4CsLPts0-rZ9oos)